# Windows batch script to copy files containing 4 digits on the filename

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I'm trying to write a Windows batch script(.bat) which should only the copy the files(staring with "cobr.cm1*) and with 4 digits on the file name from one folder to another

Source folder:

```
cobr.cm1.002.03.2020-07-23.SDK.001001.10.xml
cobr.cm1.002.03.2020-07-23.SDK.001001.1743.xml
cobr.cm1.002.03.2020-07-23.SDK.001001.1842.xml
cobr.cm1.002.03.2020-07-23.SDK.001001.12.xml
```

Destination folder (What I'm trying to achieve):

```
cobr.cm1.002.03.2020-07-23.SDK.001001.1743.xml
cobr.cm1.002.03.2020-07-23.SDK.001001.1842.xml
```

Comment: You would have to use a `FOR /F` command to parse the output of the `DIR` command that is piped to the `FINDSTR` command.  The `FINDSTR` command has limited regular expression capability but will work in your case.  This should get you started: `FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /b cobr.cm1* ^|findstr /r /C:".*\.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.xml"') do copy "%%G" "C:\some folder path\"`

Comment: I agree, although I may make it a little more robust, `@For /F Delims^= %%G In ('Dir /B /A:-D "cobr.cm1.*.????.xml" ^| "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /R /I /C:".[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789].xml$"') Do @Copy /Y "%%G" "another"`, _(obviously replacing `another` with your actual destination)_. I might even consider, if there were known numbers of other characters between some of the dots, tightening up the `.*.` with an appropriate minimum numbers of `?`'s and `.`'s, and/or further refinements for the [tag:robocopy] match.